# Specifying class variables vs. method variables C++

Tags: c++

Here's an extremely basic example of my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int x;

void test(int x) {
    x += 3;
    cout << x << endl;

}

int main() {

    test(x);
    cout << x << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

the output is:
"3"  (new line)   "0"

How can I specify inside of the "test()" function that I want the class's 'x' variable to have the 3 added to it instead of the temp variable inside of the function?

In java you specify that you're dealing with the function/method's variable by using '"this". Is there a similar way to do this in C++?

Comment: where is the 'class' that you are talking about?

Comment: there are only functions and a global variable.

Comment: You might want to look into passing parameters to functions by value and by reference and see the difference. Because I think that is essentially what you need. There isn't a class in the example. ;)

Comment: You can access the global x by using ::x . You should read up on namespaces in C++ as that would provide a better solution especially for large apps. Also if you use a class then variables in class can be accessed by using this->x.

Comment: _In java you specify that you're dealing with the function/method's variable by using '"this"_ ... I don't think you have the correct Java terminology, so it's hard to know what you're trying to say. As others have said, you don't have any classes in this code, so the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can use `::` to specify to use global variable,
instead of local one:

```
void test(int x) {
    ::x += 3;
    cout << ::x << endl;

}
```

And it is not `class member` or so on just global and local.

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ language, create a class or struct and you can use `this->x` the same as `this.x` in the Java language.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for stating that you come from Java. This will help us *a lot* in terms of helping you!

Now, let's analyze your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Including some headers, using the `std` namespace (not recommended, BTW), everything's okay here.

```
int x;
```

You declare a variable named `x` of type `int` at global scope, with an initial value of zero (this only applies to objects at global scope!).

```
void test(int x) {
    x += 3;
    cout << x << endl;

}
```

You declare a function `test` that takes a parameter `x` of type `int` and returns `void` (a.k.a: nothing). The function increments the value of its intenral `x` variable by 3, then prints that to standard output by means of `std::cout`. Just to be clear, once you declare the `int x` parameter, it "hides" the `int x` at global scope, thus if you want to access the later, you have to use another way (see below).

```
int main() {
    test(x);
    cout << x << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

You declare the special `main` function, taking no parameters and returning `int`. The function calls `test` with the global `int x` as argument, then prints the value of the global `x` to the standard output by means of `std::cout`, and finally `return`s zero, indicating successful execution.

Now, you have a big misconception, that you can attribute to the single-paradigm design of the Java language. In Java, there's no concept of "global functions", not to even say there are no "functions" at all. You only have "classes" with "methods".

In C++, this is not the case. The C++ language is a *multi-paradigm* one; it allows you to do imperative programming, structured programming, object-oriented programming, and even functional programming (you're not expected to have understood that last sentence completely)! When you declare *anything* without specifying an scope, it's said to lie in the *global* scope. The global scope can be accessed by *anything*, *anywhere*. In the example you presented **there are no classes involved**!

In the global scope, something like `void test(int)` is **not** a method, but a **function**. There's no class "owning" that function; let's say it's of "everyone" ;). A function is just a block of code that you can reuse by giving it arguments, if the function has them at all. In C++, you use classes to encapsulate data and corresponding code in a single "packed" black-box entity, not for, well, anything, like in Java.

Now, (this is somewhat like Java, but be careful!), when you pass a "plain" object, such as an `int` or something more funky and complex like `std::` (you were not expected to understand that...) to a function, that function gets a *copy* of that object. The `int x` in `test` is *not* the same as the one `main` passed to it. If you assign to it inside `test`, you'll notice `main` "sees no difference". In Java, this applies too, but only to the fundamental types like `int`, but in C++ it does for all types.

If you want to be able to change the variable you got, just use references. You get a reference of any type `T` by typing `T&`. So, if you assign to a `int& x` inside the now modified `test`, `main` will "see" all changes.

Finally, there's the `::` operator. It's used to access stuff in some scope from, well, other scopes. It has the form `namespace-or-class::stuff`. So for example, `std::cout` refers to identifier `cout` in namespace `std`. There's a special case: if the left operand is not given, `::` accesses the global scope. This is useful whenever you "hide" something from the global scope. So, for example, in `test`, you could say `::x`, and that would refer to the `x` in the global scope!

```
void test(int x) {
    // ...
    ::x += 123;
}
```

**Edit**: If you're curious, you can take a glance at how classes in C++ work with this (I won't explain it, because that's off-topic)...

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;

class MyClass {
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        MyClass() : x(0) {}

        void test(int x) {
            this->report(x);
            std::cout << "Doing some magic...\n";
            this->x += x;
            this->report(x);
        }

        void report(int x) {
            std::cout << "this->x = " << this->x << '\n';
            std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
        }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    c.report();

    x += 123;
    c.test(x);
    x += 456;
    c.test(x);

    c.report();
}
```